# Hotelling's T^2 test example using Mahalanobis distance to determine difference between groups

Tags: r, significance, t-test, mahalanobis

I'm am trying to follow the procedure described in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251529802_Quantification_and_statistical_significance_analysis_of_group_separation_in_NMR-based_metabonomics_studies) publication to determine whether separation between groups is statistically significant. The level of that publication is above my knowledge skyline, but I'm trying to approach it step by step.

For clarification and simplicity the iris dataset is used as an example and the analysis is carried out in R. As indicated by the PCA plot the method should enable me to determine whether the distances between the groups/species are significantly different.
[image: Iris Species PCA plot]

As far as I understood to get to this result the procedure comprises the following four steps:

1. Distance calculation: Using the Mahalanobis distance between the groups centroids from the first two principal components.
2. Students t-test: Employing Hotelling's two-sample T^2 statistic to determine whether separation btw. clusters is statistically significant.
3. Compute an F-Statistic: Convert T^2 statistic to F-values and compute an F-test to indicate whether there's a separation between the clusters.
4. Perform an hypothesis test using the F-statistic: If the F-value is greater than the critical F-value, then the null hypothesis, which assumes that there is no separation between the groups, can be rejected.

I'm stuck between step one and two. How to use the result from the Mahalanobis distance calculation to carry out the Hotelling's T^2 test.

MWE as follows:

```
library(ICSNP)
library(ggbiplot)
data(iris)

# Mahalanobis Distance calculation Function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708113/5731401
D.sq <- function (g1, g2) {
    dbar <- as.vector(colMeans(g1) - colMeans(g2))
    S1 <- cov(g1)
    S2 <- cov(g2)
    n1 <- nrow(g1)
    n2 <- nrow(g2)
    V <- as.matrix((1/(n1 + n2 - 2)) * (((n1 - 1) * S1) + ((n2 - 1) * S2)))
    D.sq <- t(dbar) %*% solve(V) %*% dbar
    res <- list()
    res$D.sq <- D.sq
    res$V <- V
    res
}

iris.pca <- prcomp(iris[,-5], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
str(iris)
# uncomment the next line for illustrative plot
# print(ggbiplot(iris.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
df.iris.x <- as.data.frame(iris.pca$x)
df.iris.x$Species <- iris$Species

split.data = split(df.iris.x[,-5],df.iris.x$Species)
S1 = split.data[['setosa']]
S2 = split.data[['versicolor']]
S3 = split.data[['virginica']]

# calculate mahalanobis distances for the first two principal components between the groups/species
d1 <- D.sq(S1[,1:2],S2[,1:2])
d2 <- D.sq(S1[,1:2],S3[,1:2])
d3 <- D.sq(S2[,1:2],S3[,1:2])

# T-test on the first two principal components 
HotellingsT2(S1[,1:2], S2[,1:2]) #btw setosa and versicolor
HotellingsT2(S1[,1:2], S3[,1:2]) #btw setosa and virginica
HotellingsT2(S2[,1:2], S3[,1:2]) #btw versicolor and virginica
```

The Mahalanobis distance calculation returns the three distances

```
d1$D.sq = 70.7239
d2$D.sq = 97.53259
d3$D.sq = 5.910554
```

In terms of proportion they seem to be comparable to what is shown by the PCA plot. A [Hotelling T2 test](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/ICSNP/html/HotellingsT.html) on the first two principal components returns a significant result for all three comparisons. But I was wondering how to do the T-test using the previous Mahalanobis distance calculation as stated in the referred publication?

Comment: There are four steps in this method: (1) calculate Mahalanobis distance (2) calculate Hotelling's T2-statistic (3) calculate the F-statistic from T2-statistic (4) perform an hypothesisi test using the F-statistic (* If the F-value is greater than the critical F-value, then the null hypothesis, which assumes that there is no separation between the groups, can be rejected* )

Comment: Thanks @MarcoSandri for that pointer, will change it in the description!

Comment: In my opinion at point (2) there is not hypothesis testing. The test is only at step (4).

Comment: @MarcoSandri I think you're right. Step (2) is just about calculating the Hotelling's T2 statistics and not testing any hypothesis. In my example the latter hypothesis testing is carried out by `HotellingsT2()` and the former stats should be provided by  the `hotelling.stats()` function.